# usage of find() versus count() in C++ container

Tags: c++, count, find

I am solving an interview practice problem as described below:

> Find top k frequent words in realtime data stream.
>
> Implement three methods for Topk Class:
>   --- TopK(k). The constructor.
>   --- add(word). Add a new word.
>   --- topk().
>   Get the current top k frequent words.

I wrote the following code, and it can NOT be compiled

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

unordered_map<string, int> wordcount; 

class TopK {
public:
    struct comp {
        bool operator()(const string &a, const string &b) {
            if (wordcount[a] != wordcount[b]) {
                return wordcount[a] > wordcount[b];
            }
            return a < b;
        }
    };

    set<string, comp> topkWords;
    int limit;

    TopK(int k) {
        // initialize your data structure here
        limit = k;
    }

    void add(string& word) {
        // Write your code here
        if (wordcount.count(word) == 0) {
            wordcount[word] = 1;
        } else {
            wordcount[word]++;
        }

        if (topkWords.size() < limit) {
            topkWords.insert(word);
        } else {
            if (topkWords.count(word) == 0) {
                string toDel = *(--topkWords.end());
                wordcount[toDel]--;
                topkWords.erase(--topkWords.end());
                topkWords.insert(word);
            }
        }
    }

    vector<string> topk() {
        // Write your code here
        vector<string> res;
        for (string i : topkWords) {
            res.push_back(i);
            if(--limit == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    TopK obj(3);
    string s = "leet";
    obj.add(s);
    s = "code";
    obj.add(s);
    s = "code";
    obj.add(s);
    vector<string> res = obj.topk();
    for (string s : res) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with the following error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:2043:13: No matching function for call to object of type 'const value_compare' (aka 'const TopK::comp')

if I change in add() the line

```
if (topkWords.count(word) == 0) {
```

to be

```
if (topkWords.find(word) == topkWords.end()) {
```

then everything works correctly.

So I guess this is something to do with usage of count() and find(). I checked cplusplus.com for information about the two functions. Their return types are of course different, but they both use the comparator (in struct comp for my code) to find the element equal to the function argument. This is what I am confused about. Why count() does not work and why find() works well. Could anyone give me more detailed explanation than cplusplus.com. Thank you.

---

UPDATES. my comp::operator() is not const. If I add const to comp::operator(), count() works as well. I know using operator() is necessary, and I should have done that. Why find() does not mind using non-const comp::operator()?

Comment: Consider the return value of `cmp` when strings are equal.

Comment: Your `comp::operator()` is not const.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! I add const to comp::operator() and count() works as well. Why find() does not mind using non-const operator() ? I know using const operator() is necessary...

Comment: Your comparison is wrong as you change order by incrementing `wordcount`. you should have UB in both cases so.

Comment: @JohnTan In this case, the comparator instance is stored as a member in one of the base classes of `std::set`. `find()` has both a const and non-const overload, whereas `count()` only a const.

Comment: @DanMašek I got it. I checked the cplusplus.com and count() is const while find() is not explicitly defined as const. Great answer, thank you!